# Fetch recent comments of a post in facebook

Tags: facebook

I am using graph api to fetch the posts from facebook. By default facebook provides two comments per post. But lets says after several weeks, a comment is made on a very old post. Then how can I get this comment. I mean, I am currently fetching the posts page by page bookmarking the last page from where I had read the posts data.

So how can I get this comment on an old post.Do I have to go page by page to get the comment again or there is some kind of work around so that I can pull this new comment.

Any suggestions